# type x is misisng the following properties from type but the 2 type values are different types

Tags: typescript

```
type _VariableTypes = "propertyA"|"propertyB"

interface _VariableValues {
    propertyA?: {
        value: string
        type: "INCLUDE"|"EXCLUDE"
    }

    propertyB?: {
        value: number
        type: "INCLUDE"|"EXCLUDE"
    }
}

class Achievement {
    private Data:_VariableValues

    constructor () {
        this.Data = {}
    }

    addVariable ( type:_VariableTypes, value:_VariableValues ) {
        this.Data[type] = value
    }
}
```

```
(parameter) type: _VariableTypes
Type '_VariableValues' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; type: "INCLUDE" | "EXCLUDE"; } & { value: number; type: "INCLUDE" | "EXCLUDE"; }'.
  Type '_VariableValues' is missing the following properties from type '{ value: string; type: "INCLUDE" | "EXCLUDE"; }': value, typets(2322)
```

I have no idea why this is giving me an error, I am using the same type but it is saying something is missing. I tried changing `interface` to `type` but it wouldn't solve the error

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in this way.

```
type Propertytypes = "propertyA"|"propertyB"
type Type = "INCLUDE" | "EXCLUDE"

type VariableTypeA = {
    value: string,
    type: Type
}

type VariableTypeB = {
    value: number,
    type: Type
}

type VariableTypes = VariableTypeA | VariableTypeB

type DataType = Record<Propertytypes, VariableTypes>

class Achievement {
    private Data: DataType

    constructor () {
        this.Data = {} as DataType
    }

    addVariable ( type: Propertytypes, value: VariableTypes ) {
        this.Data[type] = value
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUpIGcoF4oCIyLKgCCuAPvoRCiAEK4BQa0AKuNDrgJIByAwgBkAqgBEAorihk8YgBqDREhk3ZQAagEM4ASw0AjADYQ2kYtigBvBlBtQAbhoMBXCAC4o6YDoB2AcwA01rbM7iYQDAC%20yszqWrqGxuy05la29o4u7t5OALZ61IFpIVBhkdGqmjr6RmGYOJXxNexm0g3ViZC05ZBQIhrAGmHmAEoQAMYIcAAmADzwSNSo7Oj%20sVUJtQB8ymMGGuiYxGMAFtoQdhA5EN7AlkE2BNoOwNB9A%205vg%20zKaRPennAnGNgJMoAAKACUdzSRVO6AAdJ8UhEoPtev0vpB7lAotiNFMpm0EuCoMV5kQQMwVulnG41o0OhBMFDUjCbMA4YiMQBtZgAXXMDlp2KiESAA)